# Randomization testing in Bayesian spatial scan statistics

Tags: probability, bayesian, algorithms, spatial

I was reading about Bayesian Spatial Scan statistics [paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDgQFjAA&url=http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips18/NIPS2005_0513.pdf&ei=kTyJUbeOLKrP0gHIkIAY&usg=AFQjCNFKJVOWSum-Q2ww68it_1CmFE1Ppg&sig2=9z1YEydlJhkA6BKiNxAv0w&bvm=bv.45960087,d.dmQ). I have this confusion about why randomization testing is not necessary in this approach. The paper says that it is by construction. But, I didn't get how it is so?

Comment: Not really a solution, but why not simply email the authors with your question?  Most academics are more than happy to answer questions/emails about the work they have published.